# How to block a page from reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-select

I'm creating a search bar using react select
All is working fine. When I press on the keyboard the filter works and the enter button trigger a function which is onChange
The problem is when the filter doesn't find result and shows empty space and I press enter. The page reload it self.
If I make e.preventDefault() on the "ENTER" key, it will block the reload of the page but the "ENTER" will not trigger any function. it's blocked
is there any solution? Thank you

```js
  <Select
                        value={makeItNull}
                        placeholder={'Search...'}
                        options={options}
                        openMenuOnClick={false}
                        closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                        escapeClearsValue={true}
                        isClearable={true}
                        onKeyDown={(e) => {
                          if (e.code === "Enter") {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            console.log(e)
                          }
                        }}
                        onChange={(obj) => {
                          filterCondidateList(obj.value)
                        }}


                      />
```

Comment: Just don't always call `e.preventDefault();`; check the filter result first.

Comment: but the user can be in rush.
he is creating a list and imagine on last one he missclicked on empty space .. the whole list will dissapear.